# Can ordering of toLowerCase and normalize matter?

Tags: unicode, unicode-normalization

I want to ignore both case differences and composition differences between strings, so I have

```
function normalize(text) {
    return text.normalize("NFD").toLowerCase();
}
```

It's in Javascript, but in principle that shouldn't be important, the question is about Unicode.

Given

```
function normalize1(text) {
    return text.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD");
}
```

are there `text1` and `text2` such that `normalize` returns the same result on them but `normalize1` doesn't, or vice versa? If the answer is "yes", is one of these normalizations "more correct" in some sense?

The scenario is that my program maintains a list of phrases, and needs to determine if a given webpage contains any of them. It is preferable to have false negatives rather than false positives, as phrases can be easily added (which is why I didn't go with NFKD decomposition instead).

Secondary question: are `normalize(text)` and `normalize1(text)` ever different in the first place? If not, then the answer to the main question is also clearly "no".

Comment: If I remember correctly, there were few cases where order matter (and IIRC, it was just "historical bugs"). Later I'll check, but if I forgot, you can check on unicode tables, early "European" blocks (lower and upper cases are mostly European writing stuff, early as "one of the first allocated blocks, later Unicode addition were more precise)

Comment: For the second question: you should specify the use. For collation, for searching, for "uniqueness" (e.g. usernames), ...

Comment: I do not find any counterexample (on my references). Additionally just testing single codes, there are no differences between the two [using python and "lower()" as unicode algorithm. You may find useful such FAQ: http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use one of the *Default Caseless Matching* algorithms which use **case folding** instead of **case mapping**. For example, see the following quote from the [Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf) which defines the *canonical caseless match* and partially answers your question (emphasis mine):

> In  principle, **normalization needs to be done after case folding**, because case folding does not preserve the normalized form of strings in all instances. This requirement for normalization is covered in the following definition for canonical caseless matching:
>
> D145 A string X is a canonical caseless match for a string Y if and only if:
>   NFD(toCasefold(NFD(X))) = NFD(toCasefold(NFD(Y)))
>
> The invocations of canonical decomposition (NFD normalization) before case folding in D145 are to catch very infrequent edge cases. Normalization is  not required before case folding, except for the character U+0345 ͅ 
>   combining greek ypogegrammeni and any characters that have it as part of their canonical decomposition, such as U+1FC3 ῃ greek small letter eta with  ypogegrammeni. In practice, optimized versions of canonical caseless  matching can catch these special cases, thereby avoiding an extra normalization step for each comparison.

But if you're working with Javascript, you might be stuck with case mapping. As mentioned above, you should always normalize after case conversion but I'm not sure whether the prenormalization step for edge cases is required when lowercasing. If you want to be on the safe side, you might even consider:

```
function normalize(text) {
    return text.normalize("NFD").toLowerCase().normalize("NFD");
}
```

That said, I can't come up with an example where the order of NFD normalization and lowercasing matters (NFC and other case conversions are different, though). So in practice you're probably fine with either of the two functions in your question.